# Deleting a Base pointer that is pointing to a Derived object

Tags: c++, memory-management, casting, polymorphism, object-slicing

Will this work, or will there be slicing (i.e. only the memory corresponding to that occupied by a Base object will be freed, rather than for the whole Derived object):

```
Base* ptr = new Derived;
delete ptr;
```

If not, will this?

```
delete static_cast<Derived*>(ptr);
```

Comment: If the destructor of `Base` is `virtual`, everything will be okay. The compiler will most likely warn you if this is not the case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work.

Calling methods of a derived object by a base object pointer, is one of polymorphism fundamentals.

However, be sure that the base class destructor is virtual, to properly destruct your object.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm just a bit tired, I think :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a object slicing . Object slicing happens when you cast a derived object to base object .Here you are manipulating a pointer . you can always make base class destructor virtual will make sure that the objects are deleted  in the opposite order of creation